# A moment problem on $[0,1]$ in which infinitely many moments are equal

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

Suppose $\mu$ and $\nu$ are two probability measures on $[0,1]$. Let their $n$-th moments be denoted by $\mu_n$ and $\nu_n$, respectively, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

If we know that $\mu_n=\nu_n$ for infinitely many $n$, can we conclude that $\mu=\nu$?

One way to resolve this would be to see if the span of $\{ x^n \mid n \in S \}$ with $|S|=\infty$ is dense in the set of continuous functions $C[0,1]$. Is such a set always dense?

Comment: @Davide Giraudo: Thanks for the Muntz-Szacz theorem!

Comment: Trivial correction: it's the *Müntz–Szász theorem* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCntz%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A1sz_theorem

Comment: Why does this question have two votes to close as "off-topic?"

Comment: @DouglasZare Agreed - the M-S theorem is hardly "obvious", not is it as far as I know part of the standard diet.

Comment: @Davide Giraudo: Interesting. Applying the Hahn-Banach theorem, that answers the question. $\mu=\nu$ is guaranteed if and only if $\sum_{n\in S}\frac1n=\infty$.

Comment: @GeorgeLowther Thank you! Now an interesting problem would be to exhibit, if it exists, an example where $\nu_k=\mu_k$ on a set $S$ for which $\sum_{n\in S}\frac 1n<\infty$, but the measures are not the same.

Comment: @GeorgeLowther I agree that from Muntz-Szasz, a routine Hahn-Banach argument produces a signed measure not identically zero whose "moments vanish on S", but how do you then get two prob measures whose moments agree on $S$? (It's the norm 1 normalization condition which is bugging me, but I'm probably overlooking something stupid)

Comment: @yemon: the signed measure also vanishes on the constant functions. So, take its positive and negative components and scale them to get probability measures.

Comment: @GeorgeLowther Of course. Thanks. (That will teach me to write before the first coffee of the day.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We actually have that $\mu=\nu$ is guaranteed if and only if $\sum_{n\in S}\frac 1n$ is divergent. It's a condition which translates the fact that the set of indexed $k$ such that $\mu_k=\nu_k$ has to be large enough.

Recall [Müntz-Szász](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCntz%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A1sz_theorem) theorem, which states (in particular) the following:

> **Theorem:** If $(n_k,k\geqslant 0)$ is an increasing sequence of integers with $n_0=0$, then the following conditions are equivalent:
>
> 1. the vector space generated by $\{x^{n_k},k\in\mathbb N\}$ is dense in $C[0,1]$ endowed with the uniform norm.
> 2. the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac 1{n_k}$ is divergent.

If $\sum_{n\in S}\frac 1n$ is divergent, we can conclude by density that $\mu$ and $\nu$ coincide.

If the series is convergent, we can find $F\in (C[0,1])'$ such that $F(x^n)=0$ for all $n\in \{0\}\cup S$, but $F$ is not identically vanishing (this comes from Hahn-Banach theorem). We represent $F$ as a (non-zero) signed measure $m:=m^+-m^-$ (Hahn decomposition). Since $m^+[0,1]=m^-[0,1]$, we can rescale these measures in order to get probability measures. Then with the same notations as in the OP, $m^+_n=m^-_n$ for all $n\in \{0\}\cup S$, but $m^+\neq m^-$.

Comment: In your last sentence, where do $\mu$ and $\nu$ come from? If they are given at the start of the question, and assumed to have the same moments-indexed-by-S, then how do you know $\mu-m^+$ and $\nu+m^{-}$ are prob measures? (This is the part that I wasn't sure about, it is trivial from Hahn-Banach and Hahn-Jordan that you can find two positive measures whose moments agree on S)

Comment: @YemonChoi: I didn't understand that part of the answer either (I think Davide wants $+$ twice). But the following should work: Since $F(1) = 0 = m^+(1) - m^-(1)$, the measures $m^{\pm}$ have the same norm, so we can normalize to find two distinct nonzero probability measures measures whose moments-indexed-by-S agree by the choice of $F$.

Comment: @Martin thanks. (George Lowther suggested exactly the same, indepdendently, in comments to the main question)

Comment: @YemonChoi Indeed, my initial argument was not quite accurate. Thank you for point this out. I've edited.

Comment: Moreover, I don't think the chain of logic in your last paragraph is quite right. I don't understand why you are fixing $\mu$ and $\nu$ beforehand. What you want to prove is: if $\sum_{n\in S} n^{-1}<\infty$ then there exist two distinct probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ such that $\mu$ and $\nu$ have the same moments on $S$. As Martin and George have pointed out, this follows from taking the two parts of the Hahn-Jordan decomposition of an annihilating measure.

Comment: @YemonChoi You are perfectly right, $\mu$ and $\nu$ are unneeded.

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to move one dimension higher, then having infinitely many equal moments becomes rather weak condition. There are examples of uniform measures supported on finite polygons that have all their harmonic (a.k.a. complex) moments equal, yet the supports differ. See e.g. page 2 [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.4014v2.pdf).